# How do I set the encoding in JsonPath?

Tags: java, jsonpath

How can I set the encoding to use for JSON passed to JsonPath.parse(). There is a Configuration parameter but that does not appear to have a setting for the encoding.

And is there a way to have it use (or ignore) the BOM at the start?

I am using jayway JsonPath.

thanks - dave

Comment: Since you're asking if it can use BOM, I assume you want to read UTF-8? That's what it already uses, without BOM. The `com.jayway.jsonpath` implementation doesn't use the default encoding, it's hardcoded to use UTF-8.

Comment: @Andreas - it's two distinct questions. If there's no BOM how can I set the encoding if it's not UTF-8? We have some customers in the Far East using some other encodings. And for UTF-8, can it handle the BOM at the start ok in all cases (code I inherited is skipping over it so I'm guessing at one time JsonPath had trouble with it).

Comment: *"is there a way to have it use (or ignore) the BOM at the start?"* No

Answer (score 0):

Jayway JsonPath exposes a `read` method which accepts a charset argument.

From the [Javadocs](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html#read-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration-) ...

> public  T read(java.io.InputStream jsonInputStream,                 java.lang.String charset, Configuration configuration)
>              throws java.io.IOException

For example:

```
String json = "{\n" +
        "      \"name\" : \"john\",\n" +
        "      \"gender\" : \"male\"\n" +
        "   }";

// presumably you'll read (or get) the json in the correct charset
String value = JsonPath.compile("$.name")
        .read(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes()), "UTF-8", Configuration.defaultConfiguration());

assertThat(value, is("john"));
```

Note: this requires you to use a compiled `JsonPath` rather than the (perhaps) more user friendly API at `DocumentContext` level.